# extraer informacion en concreto de un json usando php

Tags: php, json

Tengo este código json guardado en una variable en php.

¿Cómo puedo obtener solo los datos que me interesan y extraerlos? Me gustaría hacerlo con php, es el lenguaje que estoy aprendiendo.
Una vez consiga solo esos datos, me gustaría guardarlos en una bbdd de mysql.

Me interesan estos dato que salen casi al principio:

```
"xCoord":"49",
"yCoord":"74",
"wonderName":"Gruta Sagrada de Hades",
```

y de la sección **"cities": [** necesito todos los **"ownerName":** que salen con su  **ownerAllyTag** si es que tienen

```
    [
   [
      "updateBackgroundData",
      {
         "id":"1002",
         "type":5,
         "name":"Shiariios",
         "xCoord":"49",
         "yCoord":"74",
         "tradegood":"1",
         "tradegoodTarget":"noluxury",
         "resourceLevel":"7",
         "tradegoodLevel":"5",
         "wonder":"2",
         "wonderLevel":"2",
         "wonderName":"Gruta Sagrada de Hades",
         "showResourceWorkers":0,
         "showTradegoodWorkers":0,
         "showAgora":0,
         "canEnterResource":0,
         "canEnterTradegood":0,
         "tradegoodEndUpgradeTime":0,
         "resourceEndUpgradeTime":0,
         "wonderEndUpgradeTime":0,
         "isOwnCityOnIsland":false,
         "cities":[
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "type":"city",
               "name":"Polis",
               "id":19896,
               "level":"1",
               "ownerId":"1874",
               "ownerName":"kevin23",
               "ownerAllyId":"47",
               "ownerAllyTag":"BRUTO",
               "hasTreaties":0,
               "actions":[

               ],
               "state":"",
               "viewAble":0,
               "infestedByPlague":false
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "type":"city",
               "name":"family",
               "id":14858,
               "level":"6",
               "ownerId":"4575",
               "ownerName":"Insomniocoraz0n",
               "ownerAllyId":"0",
               "hasTreaties":0,
               "actions":[

               ],
               "state":"",
               "viewAble":0,
               "infestedByPlague":false
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "type":"city",
               "name":"MauLT-V1",
               "id":11051,
               "level":"8",
               "ownerId":"3217",
               "ownerName":"Menelaus-5268",
               "ownerAllyId":"0",
               "hasTreaties":0,
               "actions":[

               ],
               "state":"vacation",
               "viewAble":0,
               "infestedByPlague":false
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"normal"
            },
            {
               "id":-1,
               "type":"buildplace",
               "name":"Terreno",
               "level":0,
               "viewAble":1,
               "buildplace_type":"premium"
            }
         ],
         "barbarians":{
            "invisible":1,
            "actionTitle":"\u00a1Ninguna tropa\/barco mercante disponible para saquear!",
            "actionClass":"plundering disabled",
            "actionLink":"",
            "count":0,
            "wallLevel":0,
            "level":0,
            "underAttack":0,
            "isTradegoodSiege":0
         },
         "avatarScores":{
            "1874":{
               "avatar_id":"1,874",
               "place":"226",
               "building_score_main":"3,312,976",
               "research_score_main":"932,580",
               "army_score_main":"129,950",
               "trader_score_secondary":"73,833"
            },
            "3217":{
               "avatar_id":"3,217",
               "place":"960",
               "building_score_main":"190,174",
               "research_score_main":"65,548",
               "army_score_main":"0",
               "trader_score_secondary":"424,331"
            },
            "4575":{
               "avatar_id":"4,575",
               "place":"858",
               "building_score_main":"351,459",
               "research_score_main":"90,808",
               "army_score_main":"9,000",
               "trader_score_secondary":"30,590"
            },
            "5948":{
               "avatar_id":"5,948",
               "place":"1,902",
               "building_score_main":"0",
               "research_score_main":"0",
               "army_score_main":"0",
               "trader_score_secondary":"16,915"
            }
         },
         "specialServerBadges":[

         ],
         "selectedCityParameters":[

         ],
         "island":1002,
         "isHeliosTowerBuilt":false,
         "heliosTop":1,
         "heliosMid":1,
         "heliosBase":1,
         "heliosName":"Ruinas de torre",
         "heliosTooltip":"Torre de Helios inactiva",
         "heliosActive":0,
         "showResourceBonusIcon":0,
         "showTradegoodBonusIcon":0,
         "walkers":{
            "add":[

            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   [
      "updateTemplateData",
      ""
   ],
   [
      "popupData",
      null
   ],
   [
      "ingameCounterData",
      null
   ],
   [
      "removeIngameCounterData",
      null
   ],
   [
      "updateBacklink",
      null
   ]
]
```

¿Algún ejemplo, tutorial o guía que pueda seguir? Estoy empezando a estudiar programación por mi cuenta.

json en array

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "updateBackgroundData"
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (37) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "1002"
      ["type"]=>
      int(5)
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Shiariios"
      ["xCoord"]=>
      string(2) "49"
      ["yCoord"]=>
      string(2) "74"
      ["tradegood"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["tradegoodTarget"]=>
      string(8) "noluxury"
      ["resourceLevel"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["tradegoodLevel"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["wonder"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["wonderLevel"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["wonderName"]=>
      string(22) "Gruta Sagrada de Hades"
      ["showResourceWorkers"]=>
      int(0)
      ["showTradegoodWorkers"]=>
      int(0)
      ["showAgora"]=>
      int(0)
      ["canEnterResource"]=>
      int(0)
      ["canEnterTradegood"]=>
      int(0)
      ["tradegoodEndUpgradeTime"]=>
      int(0)
      ["resourceEndUpgradeTime"]=>
      int(0)
      ["wonderEndUpgradeTime"]=>
      int(0)
      ["isOwnCityOnIsland"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["cities"]=>
      array(17) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#2 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#4 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#5 (13) {
          ["type"]=>
          string(4) "city"
          ["name"]=>
          string(5) "Polis"
          ["id"]=>
          int(19896)
          ["level"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["ownerId"]=>
          string(4) "1874"
          ["ownerName"]=>
          string(7) "kevin23"
          ["ownerAllyId"]=>
          string(2) "47"
          ["ownerAllyTag"]=>
          string(5) "BRUTO"
          ["hasTreaties"]=>
          int(0)
          ["actions"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["state"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(0)
          ["infestedByPlague"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
        [4]=>
        object(stdClass)#6 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [5]=>
        object(stdClass)#7 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [6]=>
        object(stdClass)#8 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [7]=>
        object(stdClass)#9 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [8]=>
        object(stdClass)#10 (12) {
          ["type"]=>
          string(4) "city"
          ["name"]=>
          string(6) "family"
          ["id"]=>
          int(14858)
          ["level"]=>
          string(1) "6"
          ["ownerId"]=>
          string(4) "4575"
          ["ownerName"]=>
          string(15) "Insomniocoraz0n"
          ["ownerAllyId"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["hasTreaties"]=>
          int(0)
          ["actions"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["state"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(0)
          ["infestedByPlague"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
        [9]=>
        object(stdClass)#11 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [10]=>
        object(stdClass)#12 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [11]=>
        object(stdClass)#13 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [12]=>
        object(stdClass)#14 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [13]=>
        object(stdClass)#15 (12) {
          ["type"]=>
          string(4) "city"
          ["name"]=>
          string(8) "MauLT-V1"
          ["id"]=>
          int(11051)
          ["level"]=>
          string(1) "8"
          ["ownerId"]=>
          string(4) "3217"
          ["ownerName"]=>
          string(13) "Menelaus-5268"
          ["ownerAllyId"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["hasTreaties"]=>
          int(0)
          ["actions"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["state"]=>
          string(8) "vacation"
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(0)
          ["infestedByPlague"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
        [14]=>
        object(stdClass)#16 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [15]=>
        object(stdClass)#17 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(6) "normal"
        }
        [16]=>
        object(stdClass)#18 (6) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(-1)
          ["type"]=>
          string(10) "buildplace"
          ["name"]=>
          string(7) "Terreno"
          ["level"]=>
          int(0)
          ["viewAble"]=>
          int(1)
          ["buildplace_type"]=>
          string(7) "premium"
        }
      }
      ["barbarians"]=>
      object(stdClass)#19 (9) {
        ["invisible"]=>
        int(1)
        ["actionTitle"]=>
        string(55) "¡Ninguna tropa/barco mercante disponible para saquear!"
        ["actionClass"]=>
        string(19) "plundering disabled"
        ["actionLink"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["count"]=>
        int(0)
        ["wallLevel"]=>
        int(0)
        ["level"]=>
        int(0)
        ["underAttack"]=>
        int(0)
        ["isTradegoodSiege"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      ["avatarScores"]=>
      object(stdClass)#21 (4) {
        ["1874"]=>
        object(stdClass)#20 (6) {
          ["avatar_id"]=>
          string(5) "1,874"
          ["place"]=>
          string(3) "226"
          ["building_score_main"]=>
          string(9) "3,313,550"
          ["research_score_main"]=>
          string(7) "932,580"
          ["army_score_main"]=>
          string(7) "127,710"
          ["trader_score_secondary"]=>
          string(6) "72,201"
        }
        ["3217"]=>
        object(stdClass)#22 (6) {
          ["avatar_id"]=>
          string(5) "3,217"
          ["place"]=>
          string(3) "961"
          ["building_score_main"]=>
          string(7) "190,174"
          ["research_score_main"]=>
          string(6) "65,548"
          ["army_score_main"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["trader_score_secondary"]=>
          string(7) "424,331"
        }
        ["4575"]=>
        object(stdClass)#23 (6) {
          ["avatar_id"]=>
          string(5) "4,575"
          ["place"]=>
          string(3) "858"
          ["building_score_main"]=>
          string(7) "351,459"
          ["research_score_main"]=>
          string(6) "90,808"
          ["army_score_main"]=>
          string(5) "9,000"
          ["trader_score_secondary"]=>
          string(6) "30,970"
        }
        ["5948"]=>
        object(stdClass)#24 (6) {
          ["avatar_id"]=>
          string(5) "5,948"
          ["place"]=>
          string(5) "1,900"
          ["building_score_main"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["research_score_main"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["army_score_main"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["trader_score_secondary"]=>
          string(6) "17,095"
        }
      }
      ["specialServerBadges"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["selectedCityParameters"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["island"]=>
      int(1002)
      ["isHeliosTowerBuilt"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["heliosTop"]=>
      int(1)
      ["heliosMid"]=>
      int(1)
      ["heliosBase"]=>
      int(1)
      ["heliosName"]=>
      string(15) "Ruinas de torre"
      ["heliosTooltip"]=>
      string(24) "Torre de Helios inactiva"
      ["heliosActive"]=>
      int(0)
      ["showResourceBonusIcon"]=>
      int(0)
      ["showTradegoodBonusIcon"]=>
      int(0)
      ["walkers"]=>
      object(stdClass)#25 (1) {
        ["add"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "updateTemplateData"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "popupData"
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "ingameCounterData"
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "removeIngameCounterData"
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "updateBacklink"
    [1]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabajar con json en php lo más fácil es usar json_decode, en tu caso, pongamos que tienes ese JSON almacenado en $json solo tendrías que hacer:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);
echo $decoded[0][1]->xCoord;
```

El [0][1] es porque, si te fijas, tu json está metido dentro de dos arrays ([[ al inicio del json)

Una vez pasado por json_decode puedes acceder a todos sus campos usando la notación normal de php, la -> y el nombre del código que quieras acceder.

Edito:
Para acceder a la información de las ciudades deberás usar un bucle. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$owners = [];

//Este bucle recorrerá todas las ciudades una a una, guardándolas en la variable $city
foreach($decoded[0][1]->cities as $city){
    //Primero que nada reseteamos las variables para evitar problemas
    $owner = "";
    $allyTag = "";
    //Luego miramos si la ciudad que estamos examinando tiene un valor ownerName
    if(isset($city->ownerName)){
        //Si lo tiene lo guardamos en $owner
        $owner = $city->ownerName;
        //Hacemos la misma comprobación con el ownerAllyTag
        if(isset($city->ownerAllyTag)){
            //Y nuevamente guardamos el valor
            $allyTag = $city->ownerAllyTag;
        }
        //Por último, metemos en el array $owners los valores del owner y allytag
        array_push($owners, ["owner"=>$owner, "allyTag" => $allyTag]);
    }
}
```

Para luego recorrer el array `$owners` podrías usar algo así:

```
foreach($owners as $o){
    echo $o["owner"] . " - " . $o["allyTag"] . "\n";
}
```

Lo que daría como resultado:

```
kevin23 - BRUTO
Insomniocoraz0n - 
Menelaus-5268 -
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: genial, de esa forma ya tengo los dos primeros valores que necesito pero como puedo obtener ownerName y ownerAllyTag? estoy probando con el mismo metodo pero no lo consigo

Comment: Te dejo el json convertido en array en la pregunta

Comment: He editado la respuesta, espero que ahora te sirva y puedas continuar aprendiendo. Un saludo y mucha suerte @niko, aquí nunca dejamos de aprender :)